# How to delete a duplicate line iff the duplicate is directly preceeded by the same line

Tags: bash, awk, duplicates

I want to remove duplicate lines from several documents recursively across sub-directories, but a line should not be considered a duplicate *unless* the preceeding line is the same, i.e. for the lines:

```
foo
foo
foo
bar
baz
foo
bar
```

The result should be:

```
foo
bar
baz
foo
bar
```

My original solution using `awk` fails as `seen` is not the correct way to approach this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s globstar
for file in **/*.md; do
    awk '!seen[$0]++' "$file" > "temp" && mv "temp" "$file"
done
```

Comment: Edit your question to show how you'd want cases where you have 3 consecutive duplicate lines handled or state if that cannot happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what `uniq` does:

```
uniq file
```

For your given input, it yields:

```
foo
bar
baz
foo
bar
```

From `man uniq`:

> Report or filter out repeated lines in a file.
>
> Reads standard input comparing adjacent lines, and writes a copy of
>   each unique input line to the standard output.
>
> The second and succeeding copies of identical adjacent input lines are
>   not written.

Answer (score 1):

[`uniq` solution posted by @fedorqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35626388/548225) certainly works.

However if you're looking for `awk` solution then use:

```
awk '$0 != p; {p = $0}' file
foo
bar
baz
foo
bar
```

Comment: To OP: In this case there's only one field, but depending on the actual content, `$0` might be preferable.

Comment: IMHO @muru is right, it should be `$0` since the OP said `lines`. nit-pick - this would fail if the first 2 lines were blank since when the script starts `p` would be zero-or-null so `$1 != p` would fail, then `p` would get set to NULL so when the 2nd line was tested that'd also fail so the net result would be both of the first 2 lines would be deleted instead of one being left. You need to modify the test to always print the first line.